# Data analysis PCA

Tags: categorical-data, pca, data-analysis

I have a question about the functioning of PCA. I have a dataset with only 2 categorical attributes out of 9. Is it good to calculate pca between those two? Does it help me understanding anything special? 
here's my [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/chocolate-bar-ratings)

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by PCA between those two? PCA is a way to understand the structure of the data as a whole, not necessarily about inner relationships

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still learning and I haven't clear ideas about it... But thanks for answering me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCA is [not recommended](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Should_I_use_PCA_with_categorical_data) for categorical features. There are equivalent algorithms for categorical features like [CATPCA](http://amse-conference.eu/history/amse2015/doc/Sulc_Rezankova.pdf) and MCA.

[image: Decision tree for dimensionality reduction based on data types]

Comment: Thank you very much @Rusoiba!!! Now it's clear!